# Running vue reactivity effects outside components (e.g. nodejs or unit tests)

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

I have a model object with logic using vue reactivity primitives inside numerous business rules invoked within multiple `watchEffect()`. How can I run those effects reactively? In other words I'm looking at alternative to `this.$nextTick`-like functionality that can work just using vue reactivity core and without any vue components. I need to invoke it from node.js backend and from unit tests. Here's an example:

```
import { test } from 'vitest'
import { ref, watchEffect } from 'vue'

test('simpleReactivity', async () => {
  const businessModel = ref(0)
  watchEffect(() => console.log('counter = ', businessModel.value))
  ++businessModel.value

  await new Promise(setTimeout) // <- todo: replace with something better

  console.log('thank you come again')
})
```

I cannot use `watchSyncEffect` because it becomes suboptimal with multiple rules reinvoking each other. There's an undocumented `effect` function, but I don't see a good guide into it and/or schedulers.

Wish #1: avoid `@vue/test-utils`. I know there's functionality in it to do what I want, but I don't want the complexity and dependencies.

Wish #2 (this is not super critical though): I'd prefer not to require async function to run the whole thing. Something like `someInlineScheduler.runAllEffects()` instead of my ugly `await new Promise(setTimeout)` that probably will not work in all environments.